# Old, old old application

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

Sometime back in March I applied to a job with careers.stackoverflow.com - suddenly today I got an email saying I had successfully applied.

I hope this was some kind of mistake in terms of the notification email, but...

Comment: Did you get the job? :)

Comment: I've just found a couple of applications that failed our over zealous virus scan. I've now just manually approved the valid ones. If you've been sent a notification it means the application, passed a 2nd manual scan and was found to be valid - likely just using a benign script loader, which some viruses use to transport themselves in. It might be a good idea to copy and paste the content of your CV into a new document to avoid this happening with other auto application services

Comment: @mythz - can you update your MSO profile to indicate you are an employee (dealing with careers) it will reduce the confusion. Also possibly consider asking for diamond status here too.

Comment: Oops :) yep just updated my details.